# send_file in rails drops last 4KB of 16KB file when sent to client

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails

I uploaded a 16 kB PNG image into a photos database on my Rails development server using attachment_fu, and I can view the PNG image in a browser pointing to the Rails development server. So that part works fine.

When I download the file to my iPhone app, and look at the data received in the method "didReceiveData", I have two problems:

1. Sometimes the last 4 kB of the PNG file is dropped, so only 12 kB is received.
2. Other times, only 4 kB or 8 kB is sent and parts of the PNG image are not in this 4 or 8 kB received.

The first occurs when I change a parameter in send_file (like buffer_size to 16kB) and restart the server. This makes me think there is some sort of caching going on with the development server. Otherwise if I haven't changed a parameter and restarted the server, #2 above occurs.

To try and fix 1 by stopping caching in the development server, I've

A)  added to `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
   config.cache_classes = true
   config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

B)  and added the following code in the controller:

```
  response.headers.delete("Pragma")
  response.headers.delete('Cache-Control')
  response.headers["Expires"] = "#{1.year.ago}"
```

Below is the code where `send_file` is called in the controller:

```
  user_photo = Photo.find_by_id(334)
  @p = user_photo

  send_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/public" + @p.public_filename,
            :disposition   => 'inline',
            :encoding      => 'binary',
            :type          => @p.content_type,
            :stream        => false,
            :filename      => URI.encode(@p.filename),
            :buffer_size   =>  4096
  )
```

My connectionDidFinishLoading method looks like:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
[connection release];
[theConnectionData release];
}
```

Any ideas why the PNG image gets truncated by 4kB or sporadically the file doesn't get sent  at all?

Comment: The way files are sent is dramatically different depending on your web server and middleware stack.  This is happening on your development environment, right?  Are you using WEBrick, Mongrol, other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This, I guess, is the case of not using

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

Sent when a connection has finished loading successfully.

I think it would be better checking the completed image size upon completion rather than worrying about the server settings.

Comment: I am using connectionDidFinishLoading.  I've added that code above.  Is there something I am missing in the usage of connectionDidFinishLoading?  Should I be looking at the data received within connectionDidFinishLoading instead of didReceiveData?

Comment: Got it.  connectionDidFinishLoading tells me that all of the data has been received.